# fine-grained capabilities for user related capabilities

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

When we want to adjust users capabilities, we can do so quite fine-grained. For example we can configure that a certain user can edit posts. But furthermore we can limit the capability of editing posts only to particular post types (eg cap: `edit_posts`, `edit_pages`, `edit_[post_type]`). And even from there on we can go deeper and do thinks like only edit private posts of post types (eg cap: `edit_private_posts`, `edit_private_pages`); just to make sure what I mean with "fine-grained".

But when it comes to user related capabilities I'm only aware of exactly 6 capabilities, namely:

- `edit_users`,
- `delete_users`,
- `create_users`,
- `list_users`,
- `remove_users` and
- `promote_users`.

**So this is it?** What about: `edit_editor_users` (which would mean: only edit users with user role "editor"). I can't believe that the user related capabilities are really that basic!

---

When I deliver a WP site to a customer I normally don't give them access to a user with user role `administrator` but more likely something like `editor` or custom user roles as well. But when I want to allow a user role to create users than users with that role can create users with each and every user role even `administrator`s. Which would not be a good thing at all! So again. I need something like:

```
$role = get_role('editor');
$role -> add_cap('create_editor_users', true); // or in general:
$role -> add_cap('[edit|delete|create|list|remove|promote]_[user_role]_users', true);
```

Is there a non hacky way to achieve this? A Plugin would be also fine as well (by now I'm using "Members", which also only handles the 6 mentioned above).

Comment: Users already can't edit user roles higher than them. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @JacobPeattie - Actually this is my primary issue. What do you mean with "Users already can't [...]"?

Comment: Hm, after poking around I think a plugin might be handling this for me. There's a filter, [`editable_roles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/editable_roles/) that should help though.

Comment: Which plugin do you use? I use "Members" - maybe there is a better one which I don't know...